How can I make a Row with a Textfield and two stacked radio buttons in Flutter?
I have a TextField to enter the year and two RadioListTiles for AD or BC.  I would like to have a Row with the TextField first, and then the RadioListTiles stacked after that and in a smaller font size.  Can someone help?
Here's what it looks like now:

And here is the code:
          TextField(
              focusNode: inputNode,
              autofocus: true,
              keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
              controller: yearController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: "Enter the Year of the Event",
              )),

          Row(
            children: [
          
              Flexible(
                child: RadioListTile<Era>(
                  title: const Text('A.D.'),
                  value: Era.ad,
                  groupValue: _era,
                  onChanged: (Era? value) {
                    setState(() {
                        _era = value;
                      });
                  },
                ),
          
              ),
          
              Flexible(
              child: RadioListTile<Era>(
                title: const Text('B.C.'),
                value: Era.bc,
                groupValue: _era,
                onChanged: (Era? value) {
                  setState(() {
                      _era = value;
                    });
                },
                ),
              ),
          
            ],
          ),


This is how I would approach this:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 enum Era { ad, bc }

class YearInputWidget extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_YearInputWidgetState createState() => _YearInputWidgetState();
}

class _YearInputWidgetState extends State<YearInputWidget> {
  final TextEditingController yearController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode inputNode = FocusNode();
  Era? _era;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Row(
  children: [
    // TextField for Year Input
    Expanded(
      flex: 2,
      child: TextField(
        focusNode: inputNode,
        autofocus: true,
        keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
        controller: yearController,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: "Enter the Year of the Event",
        ),
      ),
    ),

    // Column for the RadioListTiles
    Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          RadioListTile<Era>(
            title: Text(
              'A.D.',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
            ),
            value: Era.ad,
            groupValue: _era,
            onChanged: (Era? value) {
              setState(() {
                _era = value;
              });
            },
          ),
          RadioListTile<Era>(
            title: Text(
              'B.C.',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
            ),
            value: Era.bc,
            groupValue: _era,
            onChanged: (Era? value) {
              setState(() {
                _era = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);

}
}

Thank you.  I'm going to try this and probably use the Radio Widget as suggested in the post below.

This is a good answer, but the RadioListTiles in the column are spaced more than needed and I can't change it.  So I used the Radio widget from the second answer with your answer and it works better.  But there's too much space still.  Any idea how to get the radio buttons closer?

This solution answered the question I asked so I will mark it as the answer.  Thank you.

You can do something like following to show textfield first and make sure to wrap textfield in Expanded as to constraint it to available space.
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: TextField(
        autofocus: true,
        keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
        controller: yearController,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: "Enter the Year of the Event",
        ),
      ),
    ),
    _buildRadio('A.D.', Era.ad),
    _buildRadio('B.C.', Era.bc),
  ],
),

Also, use Radio with a combination of Row and Text widgets to properly show them in a small view, as RadioListTile comes with a lot of default padding and other configurations that is not desirable.
Radio<Era>(
  value: value,
  groupValue: _era,
  onChanged: (Era? value) {
    setState(() {
      _era = value;
    });
  },
),
Text(
  label,
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 10,
  ),
),


You're right about the RadioListTile having too much built-in padding.  I'm new to Flutter, can you show me the complete _buildRadio method?  Should I wrap them in a column?
